# When Sitecore Developer Certificate will expire?

Tags: training-certification

I wonder how long I can use the Sitecore developer certificate, somebody tells me that it might be expired next year, but here I see other answers https://community.sitecore.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=546523a91b4770d0b8954371b24bcb06 like:

- Sitecore certifications don't expire and they're version specific.
- Just received Sitecore 9 certification and it does have expiration date written on it.

But is there a way to get to know when the certificate that you want to pass will be expired?