# Certification Exam & Expiration Dates

Tags: support, training-certification

I'm running into an odd question that I can't seem to find a clear answer to. If anyone here knows a definitive answer to this question and/or can link me to a Sitecore page that documents an answer, I would really appreciate it.

I just got my Sitecore 10 Certification and in trying to track this with the rest of my organization's certs, I came to a bit of an odd point regarding my cert's expiration. In my googling, I came to learn (and recall) that the 9.0 and 9.1 exams had been removed from Sitecore's exam offerings some time ago and replaced by the more broad "Sitecore 9" exam around the time that 9.3 came out.

So ultimately now my question is... when does my "Sitecore 10 Certification" actually expire? If Sitecore is no longer including upgrade versions in their exam/certificate titles, what do we base our expiration off of?

As an example: What does this mean for the people who have 9.0 certifications? Did all their certs expire on 31-Dec-2020, when 9.0 reached the end of its Mainstream Support period, or do they expire on 31-Dec-2022, when 9.3 reaches the end of its Mainstream Support period?

For context: https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0641167#SupportPhasesForSpecificProducts

Side Note: It seems some people are of the opinion that Sitecore certs last 3 years, while others point out that Sitecore certs don't actually expire at all for the version they apply to. Unfortunately, none of these statements I've read actually come directly from Sitecore and I can't seem to find any official documentation from Sitecore defining this.

**EDIT:** Someone on my team just pointed out that a similar question to this was asked recently: [When Sitecore Developer Certificate will expire?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/30173/when-sitecore-developer-certificate-will-expire) however, the answer there doesn't seem all that clear, either, especially not considering that the "Sitecore 10" certification doesn't come with any clearly printed expiration or info detailing any kind of expiration in the slightest.

Unfortunately, the only official statement we have from Sitecore is the following which has been quoted on a number of articles I've seen on the topic:

> Certification expiration dates are the same as the Mainstream Support
> End Date for the corresponding Sitecore version per Sitecore Product
> Support Lifecycle policy.

The problem with using this as an answer is that Sitecore doesn't make it easy to determine what the "corresponding Sitecore version" when the exam and certification are both titled "Sitecore 10" rather than "Sitecore 10.0", "Sitecore 10.1", or "Sitecore 10.2".

So while we can maybe safely say that Sitecore 9.0 certs expired in Dec 2020... when are the new Sitecore 10 certs expiring? Especially considering I took and passed the exam while Sitecore 10.2 was already released and available?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help anyone if this site allows the same question to be asked multiple times. Let's allow this for right now in case there is a nuance in your question not covered in the original, but expect the posts to eventually get merged.

Comment: Thank you, @MarkCassidy! I agree that the questions should be merged, but whomever handles that should note that these questions both now have different answers (one states a 3 year expiration, the other states no expiration) but only this post includes an answer directly from multiple teams at Sitecore and it may be a more accurate answer moving forward.

Comment: Ultimately the better answer will be reflected in the votes given by the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For XP, there is no expiration date per se for the certifications. One reason for that is that some customers are still on downlevel versions of the platform. They need support access, but it doesn't make sense to force them to upgrade their certs past where their system is.

However, whether or not a certification is useful depends a great deal on what you need it for. For instance, for a partner trying to attain tiering, they need a particular number of developers per level on a current version. If you are at a partner and currently hold a 9.x certification, you should go pass the 10 certification. Going forward, that will always be by major number, not by minor number. Check the Sitecore Partner Network for details on that.

Certifications for the SaaS products (OrderCloud, CDP, Content Hub, etc.) will likely require a periodic renewal, but we haven't announced the specific policy and renewal time for those yet. Keep an eye on SPN for that as well.

Comment: Thank you! I'm just adding this bit from my emails back and forth with Sitecore directly. Billy Collins on the Partner Engagement team (alongside the Global Training and Partner Success Desk teams) has confirmed the following: **Sitecore Certifications do not expire at all. As such, any benefits and offerings acquired via a Certification do not expire either, even if the relevancy fades.**

Comment: What Billy said re: expiration dates is technically true, in that we haven't announced the policy and renewal times on the SaaS product exams. As someone else pointed out, for support access we aren't currently checking version number. From a partner perspective, you definitely lose the benefit of tiering qualification with a non-recent certification. For access to partner technical advisors, you are expected to hold a current certification.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can find an expiration date per each Sitecore version below:
https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0641167#SupportPhasesForSpecificProducts

**Update:**
I found an article that answers the same question:
https://aldrichdev.wordpress.com/2018/05/04/when-does-sitecore-certification-expire/

PAUL ALDRICH in his blog:

> My first thought of who to ask about this was the Sitecore community
> on Slack. At first I received my mixed answers, but someone provided
> an accurate answer: every 3 years. This seemed kind of vague for me,
> so I decided to get an official answer. I ended up emailing back my
> instructor (after almost 3 years!) and asking about when it expires,
> and I got an even better answer:
>
> *Certification expiration dates are the same as the Mainstream Support*
> *End Date for the corresponding Sitecore version per Sitecore Product*
> *Support Lifecycle policy. You can find the mainstream support end date*
> *for every version of Sitecore here:*
> *https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/641167*

**Update2:**
For example, the initial release date for Sitecore 9.0 is 2017, so the mainstream support end date according to the table above is 31-Dec-2020. As I remember the Sitecore 9 certificate expired on 31-Dec-2020 for all my teammates who passed the certification exam in 2019. After searching over the internet I found some Sitecore 9.0 certifications, despite the exams were passed in 2017, 2018, or 2019, those certificates were expired on 31-Dec-2020:

1. https://martinmiles.net/Content/download/9.0.pdf
2. https://www.lyhin.com/images/Sitecore-Certified-Developer.png
3. https://miro.medium.com/max/700/1*FGqNnxq_C0GP_45hUR3RXQ.jpeg

You can find the expiration date on the left bottom.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131292/discussion-on-answer-by-alexander-when-sitecore-developer-certificate-will-expir).

Comment: Sure, @RichardSeal, thanks! BTW, I updated my answer.

Comment: Ahh yes, @Alexander, it makes sense, now it is clear why the expiration is 3 years. So, it looks like it is better to get the latest Sitecore certification.

Answer (score 0):

Adding another answer here. I emailed Sitecore's training and partnership teams directly about this topic and got a response contradicting the accepted answer.

I ended up posting a very similar question on here and have selected an answer there, too. Someone may need to merge these questions at some point; likely my own fault for not being able to find this original question when I asked mine, but for time time being the more accurate answer seems to be that Sitecore Certs do not expire: [Certification Exam & Expiration Dates](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/30489/certification-exam-expiration-dates/)

> Sitecore Certifications do not expire at all. As such, any benefits and offerings acquired via a Certification do not expire either, even if the relevancy fades.

While your certification may become less relevant over time, a developer certified with Sitecore 7 can still get support for Sitecore 10 without having to renew their certification. Likewise, it sounds to me like an organization can retain partnership status with a number of outdated certifications, but at that point it's a matter of how transparent they want to be with their clients or management regarding the aforementioned relevancy of their certifications.

Comment: I'll let Billy know that he needs to update the language he is using in replying.